# TypeError: expect(...).not.toBe is not a function

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Doing an exercise where I re-implement some functionality found in the Jasmine test framework.  Specifically, I am running this line:

`expect(false).not.toBe(true)`

and I get a TypeError saying that toBe does not exist as a function.  However, this line:

`expect(true).toBe(true)`

Passes.  I suspect that it's an issue with my not() function returning this.

```
function ExpectedValue (val) {
    this.value = val;
    this.notted = false;

    this.not = function() {
        this.notted = !this.notted;
        return this;
    }

    this.toBe = function(b) {
        if (this.notted) {
            return this.value !== b;
        }
        else {
            return this.value === b;
        }
    }
}

function expect(a) {
    return new ExpectedValue(a);
}

console.log(expect(false).not.toBe(true));
```

Comment: Why aren't you invoking the function? `expect(...).not().toBe(...)`

Comment: I'm invoking the function in a wrapper.  I added a console.log at the end to show essentially what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine's `not` **isn't** a function. Yours is. But you're using it as though it were Jasmine's (without `()`):

```
console.log(expect(false).not.toBe(true));
// Note no () ---------------^
```

Your `not` needs to be an object with all of the methods of the object you return from `expect`, but with their meaning inverted, e.g.:

```js
function ExpectedValue (val) {
    var self = this;
  
    self.value = val;

    this.not = {
        toBe: function(arg) {
            return !self.toBe(arg);
        }
    };

    this.toBe = function(b) {
        return self.value === b;
    };
}

function expect(a) {
    return new ExpectedValue(a);
}

console.log(expect(false).not.toBe(true));
```

There, it's manual, but that's not scaleable. Instead, you'd have an object with all of the methods on it, and create `not` by running through creating functions that invert the return.

```
arrayOfMethodNames.forEach(function(name) {
    target.not[name] = function() {
        return !target[name].apply(target, arguments);
    };
});
```

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense!  Thank you!